# What is the output when Declaring static Variable and why?

Tags: c++

[image]
[image]
I am little bit confuse why the value of static variable change when I am doing ++i?

```
 void hd()
{
int i = 10;
static int j = 20;
printf("i=%d j=%d",++i,++j);
}

main()
{
hd();
hd();
}
```

output 
i = 10 j = 21
i = 10 j = 21

Why the value of J change?

Comment: because you've incremented it...

Comment: I recall being asked a very similar question in Uni. It was in C Programming 101.

Comment: "i = 10 j = 21 i = 10 j = 21" This is not the output I get.

Comment: I got  i=11 j==21 both the time

Comment: But why they change value j=21 ,ya I did pre increment but I have declared static for j ?

Comment: Don't post images of text! And use a mopre recent toolchain, That seems to be Turbo-C++, which is outdated since over 20 years now and does not support standard C++ (nor C).

Comment: Don't spam tags. You are most certainly not building objective-c with a compiler that predates that language.

Comment: @StoryTeller: From the file-extension, it is C++. I changed the tag accordingly. But Objective-C is older than you might think.

Comment: @Olaf - I don't care what it is, so long as there's no tag spam. But I suppose it's a fool's hope to think there will ever not be tag spam... And yeah, I just googled Objective-C (shows my age :) ). But still very much doubt Borland Turbo C++ supported it.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Indeed, it is. But apparently, I'm a fool ,too ;-) Maybe only one language tags should be allowed by default and if posters insist, the question should require a review before it is opened for answers.

Comment: The code you posted and the code you are using are two different things. `static int j = 20;` behaves a lot differently than `static int d; d = 60; `.

Answer (score 0):

A variable declared `static` in a function is only initialised the first time the line is executed.

Comment: it shoud be 11 21 11 22

Comment: That's wrong. All static objects are initialised before `main` is called, not on the first execution of a function. And definitions are not "executed".

Comment: @Olaf - Not to be pedantic, but now that you re-tagged it as C++,  it is indeed correct that the object is value-initialized only on the first entry to the function.

Comment: @StoryTeller That's interesting, I didn't actually know that. Just wondering, is it function entry or scope?

Comment: [Scope](https://ideone.com/UVbGag). The example is a bit convoluted, since the only real way to get a feel for it is to interrupt initialization with an exception.

Comment: @StoryTeller: You are right. I wrote the comment before I noticed the filename. The difference is relevant if the constructor has certain side-effects, no need for an exception to happen. (but such problems are often from a bad code design anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: all of the statements in your hd() function other than your static declaration are executed everytiime hd() is invoked.

If that doesn't help, use a debugger and watch the value of j as you step through hd().